# Parse bbcode with arrays

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

following problem: [image: List isn't shown correctly]
The "li"-tag from the upper "list" isn't correct set and then it is.
I tried to change expressions but I found no solution yet.

This is my (shortended) code (and all other "bb"s following the same schematic)

```
function bb($content) {
$search = array (
'#\[list\](.+)\[\/list\]#iUs',
'#\[list=1\](.+)\[\/list\]#iUs',
'#\[\*\](.*)\[/\*\]#iUs',
'#\[IMG\](.+)\[\/IMG\]#iUs'
);
$replace = array (
'<ul>$1</ul>',
'<ol>$1</ol>',
'<li>$1</li>',
'<img src="$1"/>' 
);
$newtext = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
$newtext = nl2br($newtext);
$newtext = preg_replace('#<br />(\s*<br />)+#', '<br />', $newtext);
return $newtext;
}
print autolink(bb($NewsItemContent)); // http/s autolinking (later I'll add link preview)
```

Content will look like this:

```
 [h1]MAIN FEATURES[/h1] [list] [*]Doubles https://steamcommunity.com/games/227300/announcements/detail/1294067099912833659 [*]Background screen options [*]Changed light flares on the player and AI vehicles https://steamcommunity.com/games/227300/announcements/detail/1335730452506903011 [/list] [h1]MINOR CHANGES[/h1] [list][*]Auxiliary brakes system support (engine brake and retarder in one control element)[/*][*]Fixed licence plate change in states/countries where no city formats exist[/*][*]Fixed brake vs parking brake behavior[/*][*]Fixed tire noise of silent tires[/*][*]Retarder improvement (better cruise control behavior, no braking with throttle, icon when moving only)[/*][*]Steam Inventory support to allow for distributing rewards from upcoming World of Trucks events[/*][/list] If you wish to participate in the open beta, you can find this version in the public_beta branch on Steam. The way to access it is as follows: Steam client → LIBRARY → right click on Euro Truck Simulator 2 → Properties → Betas tab → public_beta → 1.28 public beta. No password required. During open betas, there is a dedicated beta site for World of Trucks, which is used to safely test all new features.
```

[image: Full Content]

I hope anybody can help me, 
Cheers'

Comment: Could you please show what *content* you're sending to `bb`?

Comment: Sorry for that I'll update it now. //Updated it

Comment: Not solving problem, but this `'#\[\*\\](.*)\[\/\*\\]#iUs'` only matches this `[*\]asdf[/*\]` .. and it should be this `'#\[\*\](.*)\[/\*\]#iUs'` Also, using `.*` will match to the end of the line, even other tags.

Comment: You have two differents bbcode item syntaxes in your example: the first uses only `[*]` to start a new item, the second ends the item with a closing tag. Which one is correct? (I have already seen the first but never the second)

Comment: It may deletes because the hyperlink in it - saw it right know, thank you Casimir. (I'm currently using Steam's api to fetch json - http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=227300&count=3&format=json). That would be the problem... missing ending closing-tag. Didn't saw this.

Comment: And, since you have the dot-all modifier, `.*` will actually jump right to the _end_ of the string and backtrack to find the closing tag.

Comment: Whatever, you can build a pattern that handles the first syntax (without closing tag) and that removes the eventual closing tag if any.

Comment: The regex part is simple, you could combine all this into a single regex. However, seeing what you want to do requires somebody debugging your code. It's like pulling teeth.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation you have given here - which _modifier_ should I use instead of ``.*``?  If I use the ``.*?`` the function isn't correct (output [*]Text). At this moment I have to use at least ``.*`` to display text without a ``Compilation failed``-warning. (I'm new to regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bbcode flavours with different syntaxes. Obviously the best is to have a clear rule and to handle only one syntax, but for your specific problem, you can change your pattern to something like this:

```
#\[\*]([^[]*(?:\[(?!/?\*]|/list])[^[]*)*)(?:\[/\*])?#i
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/utO37)

Note that you also need to put the `[*]` replacement before the `[list]`s replacements.

The idea is to describe all that isn't a `[*]`, `[/*]` or `[/list]`, and to add an optional closing tag at the end.

details:

```
\[\*]   # opening tag
 (    # capture group 1
     [^[]* # all that isn't an opening square bracket
     (?:
        \[ (?!/?\*]|/list]) # opening bracket not followed by *] or /*] or /list]
         [^[]*
     )*
 )
 (?:\[/\*])?    # the optional closing tag
```

Comment: To be honest - I don't understand the syntax. If I replace my "star"-syntax with yours the output will look fine for the first moment, but I'll get too much ending tags and missing start-tags like here: (missing start-tag)``Auxiliary brakes system support (engine brake and retarder in one control element)[/*]`` (and added end tag - then correct start tag)
``• Fixed licence plate change in states/countries where no city formats exist[/*]`` (added one end tag too much)

http://prntscr.com/g1y5wh

//edit: wow fast edit to explanation - thanks!

Comment: @Kaan2106: sorry I made a typo, (I have forgotten the slash in the closing tag.)

Comment: @Kaan2106: You also need put the items replacement before the list(s) replacements in your arrays. (since the pattern refers to the `[/list]` bbcode)